# Is there any way to get the date modified from Net::SSH or NET::SFTP commands in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, sftp, net-sftp

Is there an easy way to get the date modified of a file by using Net::SFTP?

It'd be nice to be able to do this:

```
Net::SFTP.start('some_server') do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.glob('*').each do |file|
    puts file.mtime
  end
end
```

But that's not possible (to my knowledge).

Berns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your example code is almost there, you just need to use `file.attributes.mtime` where you had `file.mtime`.

Also, I'm guessing the code in the question was just an example, but in order for it to execute you also need to pass the username and password to `start` and pass the path as well as the pattern to `glob`. So a working example would be:

```
Net::SFTP.start('some_server', 'mike', :password => 'secret') do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.glob('.', '*').each do |file|
    puts file.attributes.mtime
  end
end
```

The value returned by `mtime` will be the number of seconds since the epoch so you may want to pass it to [Time.at](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000251) to convert it to a `Time` object.

In case you're curious, the other attributes available in the same way are:

- `permissions`
- `uid`
- `gid`
- `size`
- `atime` (time of last access)

Comment: Beautiful! And excellent catch on the other example mishaps. Thanks Mike!